# How do I change this html code to make my tumblr background not repeat and fill the entire page?

Tags: html, css, background, tumblr

```
body {
color: #1a1a1a;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 19px;  

background: url('http://www.totallylayouts.com/backgrounds/hipster/triangle_in_the_woods.jpg')
```

no-repeat top left scroll;

I tried to put in background-size: 100% 100%; however it did nothing....

Answer (score 2):

From http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

A CSS only solution, that works for any screen resolution, without any white space:

```
 html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning the browser support (IE9+): http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Answer (score 0):

You can make it not repeat via `background-repeat:no-repeat;` but you can't make it fill the whole page, at last you can resize the background via `background-size: 0px 0px;`

here you go!

```
  body {
    color: #1a1a1a;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 19px;  

    background-image: url('http://www.totallylayouts.com/backgrounds/hipster/triangle_in_the_woods.jpg') 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:1920px 1080px;
```

Answer (score 0):

If kunoo's solution does not work for you (because you need to support older browsers, mainly the evil IE), then there is a [nice jquery plugin named backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/). I use it quite a lot and it's working flawlessly. It makes a background image fit the whole screen, even when resizing the window.